# how can I recreate these graphs?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I am looking to recreate these graphs shown in [this link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2832910/figure/F2/):

[image]

I need to have them in the correct order and I am also unsure about what k values I need to use for each graph.
I have tried a few k values but can't seem to get it correct. My code is shown below.
Any help would be great, thanks.

```
#define parameters
k1= np.linspace(0,1,2)
k2=1
n1=3
n2=3
K1=0.3
K2=0.3
beta1=0
beta2=0.05
x = np.linspace(0,1)
def r_inact_1loop(x,k1=1):      #np.linspace(10,0,0.5)): #k1=1
    return k1*x
def r_activation(x,k1=1):     #np.linspace(0,1,2.5))
    return k2*(beta2*K2**n2/(K2**n2+x**n2) + x**n2/(K2**n2+x**n2))*(1-x)
def r_inact_2loop(x,k1=1):   #np.linspace(2.5,0,1)):
    return k1*(beta1*x**n1/(K1**n1+x**n1) + K1**n1/(K1**n1+x**n1))*x

#graphs
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,5))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
ax1.set_xlabel('Fraction of activated A')
ax2.set_xlabel('Fraction of activated A')
ax3.set_xlabel('Fraction of activated A')
ax1.set_ylabel('Rate of A inactivation or activation')
ax2.set_ylabel('Rate of A inactivation or activation')
ax3.set_ylabel('Rate of A inactivation or activation')

for k in k1: #k1
    ax1.plot(x, r_inact_1loop(x,k),label='in1 k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    ax1.plot(x, r_activation(x,k),label='ac k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    #ax1.legend(loc='best')
    ax2.plot(x, r_inact_1loop(x,k),label='in1 k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    ax2.plot(x, r_inact_2loop(x,k),label='in2 k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    #ax2.legend(loc='best')
    ax3.plot(x, r_activation(x,k),label='ac k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    ax3.plot(x, r_inact_2loop(x,k),label='in2 k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
    #ax3.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlim(0,1)
    plt.ylim(0,0.7)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `r_activation` function doesn't seem right to me:

```
def r_activation(x,k1=1):     #np.linspace(0,1,2.5))
    return k2*(beta2*K2**n2/(K2**n2+x**n2) + x**n2/(K2**n2+x**n2))*(1-x)
```

parameter `k1` is not used.

2nd, for the 1st plot, the activation curve can be generated by `r_inact_1loop` function with `1-x` as the 1st parameter instead of `x`.

3rd, I plotted the activation/inactivation curve with different k in different line style to illustrate the affect of different `k`.

```
k=1
ax1.plot(x, r_inact_1loop(x,k),label='in1 k1={:.1f}'.format(k), c='r')
ax1.plot(x, r_inact_1loop((1-x),k),label='ac k1={:.1f}'.format(k), c='b')
ax1.plot(x, r_inact_1loop((1-x),k*0.5),label='ac k1={:.1f}'.format(k), c='b', ls='--')
#ax1.plot(x, r_activation(x,k),label='ac k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
#ax1.legend(loc='best')
ax2.plot(x, r_inact_1loop(x,k),label='in1 k1={:.1f}'.format(k), c='r')
ax2.plot(x, r_activation(x,k),label='ac k1={:.1f}'.format(k), c='b')
#ax2.plot(x, r_inact_2loop(x,k),label='in2 k1={:.1f}'.format(k))
#ax2.legend(loc='best')
ax3.plot(x, r_inact_2loop(x,k),label='in2 k1={:.1f}'.format(k), c='r')
ax3.plot(x, r_inact_2loop(x,k*2),label='in2 k1={:.1f}'.format(k), c='r', ls='--')
ax3.plot(x, r_activation(x,k),label='ac k1={:.1f}'.format(k), c='b')
#ax3.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlim(0,1)
plt.ylim(0,1)
```

[image]

4th, with 3rd being said, the red areas in the original plots are obtained as follows: keeping the activation curve constant, and changing `k` values for the inactivation curve, such that inactivation curve and activation curve at least intercept (and thus bistable is possible).  There will be a set of upper and lower bounds of `k` to make interception possible and the red area illustrate the `k` bounds (am I guess one have to numerically solve the upper and lower bounds of `k`).